# CSS positioning a div on mouse over

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip

I am trying to position a `div` dynamically, when i mouse over the div "A" another div "B" will be visible and it should be positioned below div A.Basically i am trying to achieve tool-tip kind of stuff. trying to position with jQuery, how can i do this

css for `div B`

```
.B ul li
{
font-size: 11px;
font-family: Arial;
float: left;
}

.B{

min-height:10px;  
background: #333333;
color:white;
padding:5px;
position:absolute;
word-wrap:break-word;
-moz-border-radius:5px; 
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
z-index:999;
display: none;


}

.B:after{ /*arrow added to uparrowdiv DIV*/
content:'';
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:-16px; 
left:30px;
width:0;
height:0;
border-color: transparent transparent #333333 transparent; 
border-style: solid;
 border-width: 10px;

 } 

css for `div A`

.A
{
float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
color: rgb(119, 119, 119);
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.A' ).live('mouseover',function (event){
event.preventDefault();
var B=$(this).next();
$(B).show();
$(B).css( { "margin-top" : "27px", "margin-left" : "200px" } );

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little mistake with object selector don't use $(B) but use B:

```
$('.A' ).live('mouseover',function (event){
event.preventDefault();
var B=$(this).next();
B.show();
B.css( { "margin-top" : "27px", "margin-left" : "200px" } );

});
```

You have already assigned B = $(this).next(); which is object itself so Just use B instead of $(B).

---

I also recommend you to use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of live function.

Comment: ok..will this work? B.css({top: 70, left: $(this).position().left-25}); when i use this all the div B appears in same position

Answer (score 1):

Any harm if we do it using PURE CSS? As you've tagged this with CSS too so I assume that CSS solutions are accepted..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wz8vB/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/wz8vB/3/) *(nothing fancy, just highlighted the tooltip)*

[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/wz8vB/2/) Using `transition` with `opacity`

Here, the main part is using `content` property, which on `:hover` a, revealing the content of `data-tooltip` attribute which is a [valid custom attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) as of HTML5

```
<p>This is a <span data-tooltip="showthis">tooltip</span></p>

span:after {
    display: none;
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -50px;
    background: #f00;
    padding: 10px;
}

span {
    position: relative;
}

span:hover:after {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: here in the place of showthis i wat to use the data which is retrieved from the database using php, can i show a div or the contents inside a div as tooltip

Comment: @user1851420 than you can `echo` the text in the `data-tooltip` attribute :) and I just went through your profile, you do not accept answers, so click on the tick besides answers to accept them if they help you

Comment: @user1851420 also, if you want to play with elements, than here you go http://jsfiddle.net/njgmC/